# handleMessage doesnt see my classes and functions

Tags: c++, omnet++

i'm writing this code in omnet++ that should send messages each T time from different nodes to one central node. My problem now is that the handleMessage function doesnt see the classes and function i created, while inizialize sees everything; im fairly new to programming and a newbie to the c++ language :). 
CODE:

```
using namespace omnetpp;
class Net : public cSimpleModule
{
public:   
    virtual void initialize() override;
    virtual void handleMessage(cMessage *msg) override;
};

class Central_Node : public Net
{
    simtime_t time_stamps[];
    int index;

public:
    void addTimeStamp()
    {
      int array_size = sizeof(time_stamps);
      time_stamps[array_size] = SimTime();
    }
    void deleteSignal(cMessage *msg)
    {
        delete msg;
    }
};

class Sensor : public Net
{
    int index;
    double delay;

public:
    Sensor(int a, double b)
    {
        index = a;
        delay = b;
    }

    void sendMessage()
    {
        cMessage *msg = new cMessage("Signal");
        send(msg, 0);
        cMessage *SelfMsg = new cMessage("SelfMessage");
        scheduleAt(simTime() + delay, SelfMsg);
    }
};


Define_Module(Net);

void Net::initialize()
{    
    Central_Node centralNode;
    Sensor Sensor1 (1,100);
    Sensor Sensor2 (2,210);

    Sensor1.sendMessage();
    Sensor2.sendMessage();
}

void Net::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
{
    if (getIndex() == 0) 
    {
        simtime_t ArrivalTime = centralNode.addTimeStamp();
        centralNode.deleteSignal(*msg);
    }

    if (getIndex() == 1) 
    {
        Sensor1.sendMessage();
    }

    if (getIndex() == 2) 
    {
       Sensor2.sendMessage();
    }
}
```

The error I get is:  `use of undeclared identifier 'centralNode'` on the line `simtime_t ArrivalTime = centralNode.addTimeStamp();`.

Comment: What do you mean by "the handleMessage function doesnt see the classes and function i created"?  What specifically are you observing that makes you say that?

Comment: Hi, it says "use of undeclared identifier 'centralNode' " on the "simtime_t ArrivalTime = centralNode.addTimeStamp();" line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that at the point of use, `centralNode` is not a defined variable:

```
void Net::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
{
  if (getIndex() == 0) 
  {
      // Error:  use of undeclared identifier 'centralNode'
      simtime_t ArrivalTime = centralNode.addTimeStamp();  
      centralNode.deleteSignal(*msg);
  }
  [...]
}
```

You create a `centralNode` variable in the `Net::initialize()` member function, but that is a *local variable within the function*, not a class member.  That `centralNode` variable in the `Net::initialize()` function is naturally not visible within any other member functions, including the `Net::handleMessage` member function.

There are two possible solutions.

### Option 1:  Create a local variable in Net::handleMessage

You can declare a local variable in `Net::handleMessage()`, just like the `Net::initialize()` function does.  This `Central_Node` object will "disappear" (be destroyed) once it goes out of scope.

```
void Net::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
{
  if (getIndex() == 0) 
  {
      Central_Node centralNode;    // Instantiate here before use.
      simtime_t ArrivalTime = centralNode.addTimeStamp();  
      centralNode.deleteSignal(*msg);
  }
  [...]
}
```

### Option 2:  Create a data member in the Net class

You can declare a class data member in the `Net` class.  This is complicated, however, because the `Net` class would contain a `Central_Node` data member, but the `CentralNode` class itself inherits from `Net`.

To break this circular dependency, you can forward-declare `Central_Node` and use a pointer within the `Net` class:

```
class Central_Node;  // Forward declaration

class Net : public cSimpleModule
{
    // unique_ptr required to break circular dependency
    std::unique_ptr<Central_Node> centralNode;
    [...]
};
```

### General Comments

Often, when code exhibits a circular dependency, it is a sign that the abstractions or relationships expressed in code are not the right ones.

In this case, it seems wrong that a `Central_Node` inherits from a `Net` (presumably "Network") class.  Inheritance is classically used to express an "is-a" relationship, and it is very odd to say "A Central_Node (or any Node) is a Network".  Instead, a Node (including a CentralNode) is a part of a Network, or alternatively, a Network contains Nodes.

Separately from all this, I think there is a bug in the `Central_Node:: addTimeStamp()` member function, since the array data member is never initialized.  I suspect that, as written, this will cause a segfault or other crash at runtime.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer; so how chould i change the dependency of the sensor and the centralnode classes to get it to work? And how can i inizialize the timestamps vector with variable dimension? And at the end i dont understand why the inizialize function doesnt give me any problem of declaration

Comment: As for the timestamps vector, I would suggest simply using `std::vector<simtime_t>` as a member of `Central_Node`, replacing the C-style array member.  If you have questions about how to initialize it or add timestamps, you may want to refer to a tutorial that covers `std::vector<T>`.

Comment: You wrote that you don't understand why the "initialize" function does not give you a problem in the initial code.  As I wrote, the original code includes a *local variable* in that function, and then uses the local variable.  It is valid, compile-able code, but it probably doesn't do what you want it to do (define a data member for the class).  

I'll try to add option #3 about reorganizing dependencies.

Finally, if this answered your original question about why the code wasn't working, you may consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: using the unique_ptr i manage to get no errors from the varialble used in the handlemessage funcion but i get errors from the function that i created in the classes i declared:giving no member named 'addTimeStamp' in 'std::unique_ptr<Nodo_Centrale, std::default_delete<Nodo_Centrale> >' and no member named 'deleteSignal' in 'std::unique_ptr<Nodo_Centrale, std::default_delete<Nodo_Centrale> >' and no member named 'sendMessage' in 'std::unique_ptr<Sensore, std::default_delete<Sensore> >'; did you mean to use '->' instead of '.'?

Comment: Those errors occur because, if you have a pointer variable, you need to replace the use of `.` with `->` to call member functions.  This would all be covered in an introductory C++ textbook or tutorial.  I suggest going through such a tutorial in order to make the C++ part of this project a bit easier.

Comment: It works for the lasta 2 function called but not for the first 2: member access into incomplete type 'Nodo_Centrale'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202946/discussion-between-wolz-and-nicholasm).